# Java Berkeley DB Truncate at Certain TOD

Tags: berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

I have an application which uses a very old version of Berkeley DB for Java (je-3.3.62).

I need to truncate the database at a certain time every day (the start of day) because our application allows for keys to be re-used across days (but never during the same day). The way the database is currently minimally configured, keys can never be re-used because the database is never purged of old keys.

Hoping someone can shed some insight into how to achieve this with the current version.